# Python: making one list from for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm coding for a week, and I feel lost right now I'm trying to escape from multiple lists to one and then add to CSV. The program is webscraping the site. Part 1  creates links and takes the redirecting links, then in Part 2 it is connecting to site and taking the tables. Part 3 is taking the words from HEADERS (there is about 43 words) and it's looking in description for all words and then adds 60 characters to the left from word, and 60 to the right. It is in the loop because there is plenty of real estates offers that I need take info from. Hope you're understand. Coding takes a lot of energy!

Whole program you can find here (EDIT PART): https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/90155616?noredirect=1

Here is the code:

```
for p in page_soup.select('section#description'):
            p = str(p)
            p = p.lower() 

            lista_k = []            

            for j in range(len(HEADERS3)): 
                #print('j:',j)
                # find_p znajduje wszystkie słowa kluczowe z HEADERS3 w paragrafie na stronie kontraktu.
                find_p = re.findall(HEADERS3[j],p)
                # listy, które wyświetlają pozycję startową poszczególnych słów muszą zaczynać się od '-' lub 0?,
                # ponieważ, gdy dane słowo nie zostanie odnalezione to listy będą puste w pierwszej iteracji pętli
                # co w konsekewncji doprowadzi do błędu out of range
                m_start = []
                m_end = []
                lista_j = []


                for m in re.finditer(HEADERS3[j], p):
                    #print((m.start(),m.end()), m.group())
                    m_start.append(m.start())
                    m_end.append(m.end())

                #print(h)

                for k in range(len(m_start)):
                    #właściwe teraz nie wiem po co to jest..
                    try:
                        x = m_start[k]
                        y = m_end[k]
                    except IndexError:
                        x = m_start[0]
                        y = m_end[0]
                    #print('xy:',x,y)
                    #print(find_p) 
                #print(HEADERS3[j])
                    z = (HEADERS3[j]+':',p[-60+x:y+60]+'    ++-NNN-++') 
                    lista_j.append(z)
                    #print(z)
                #print ('lista_j:',lista_j)
                lista_k.append(lista_j)
            print('lista_k:',lista_k)
```

The output is:

```
                ----------- 3 -----------
 http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-wynajem-46m2-2000pln-gorna-bezrzecze-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351353
['351353', '2', '2 000 PLN', '-', '46\xa0m2', '0', '2', 'Widna', '-', '-', 'Gazowe', 'Tak', 'Tak', 'Piec gazowy', '-', 'Cegła', '2007', 'Bardzo dobry', '-', '-', '-', 'Liczba tarasów: 2', '-', 'Ogród: Tak', '-', 'Garaż: Tak', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: [('gospodarcze:', 'arkingowe na samochód ,rower ale również jako pomieszczenie gospodarcze z półkami. cena najmu do negocjacji,warunkiem jednak koniec    ++-NBP-++')]
lista_j: []
lista_j: [('parking:', 'ie do garażu.przed garażem podjazd i ogólnodostępne miejsca parkingowe . w pobliżu wiele sklepów,między innymi dwa supermarkety    ++-NBP-++'), ('parking:', 'z śmieci i f. remontowy.garaż do wykorzystania jako miejsce parkingowe na samochód ,rower ale również jako pomieszczenie gospod    ++-NBP-++')]
lista_j: []
lista_j: [('garaż:', 'nie dwupokojowe usytuowane na parterze z tarasem ,ogrodem i garażem.budynek wybudowany w 2007r. na nowym kameralnym,bezpieczn    ++-NBP-++'), ('garaż:', 'ience piec dwuobiegowy typu vaillant .z ogrodu przejście do garażu.przed garażem podjazd i ogólnodostępne miejsca parkingowe     ++-NBP-++'), ('garaż:', 'uobiegowy typu vaillant .z ogrodu przejście do garażu.przed garażem podjazd i ogólnodostępne miejsca parkingowe . w pobliżu w    ++-NBP-++'), ('garaż:', ' 220zł w nim zaliczka na wodę , wywóz śmieci i f. remontowy.garaż do wykorzystania jako miejsce parkingowe na samochód ,rower    ++-NBP-++')]
lista_j: [('ogród:', 'in.salon z aneksem kuchennym ok 24mkw z wyjściem na taras i ogród.taras w częsci zadaszony z kącikiem z siedziskiem oraz ozdo    ++-NBP-++'), ('ogród:', 'kiem z siedziskiem oraz ozdobną pergolą w części otwarty na ogród z zadbanym trawnikiem oraz krzewami :porzeczką,borówką i ma    ++-NBP-++')]
lista_j: [('ogrod:', 'ne mieszkanie dwupokojowe usytuowane na parterze z tarasem ,ogrodem i garażem.budynek wybudowany w 2007r. na nowym kameralnym    ++-NBP-++'), ('ogrod:', 'umywalką i wc. w łazience piec dwuobiegowy typu vaillant .z ogrodu przejście do garażu.przed garażem podjazd i ogólnodostępne    ++-NBP-++')]
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: [('remon:', 'o zarządcy 220zł w nim zaliczka na wodę , wywóz śmieci i f. remontowy.garaż do wykorzystania jako miejsce parkingowe na samoc    ++-NBP-++')]
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: [('aneks:', 'miejskiej-szybki dojazd do centrum miasta ok.10 min.salon z aneksem kuchennym ok 24mkw z wyjściem na taras i ogród.taras w cz    ++-NBP-++'), ('aneks:', 'anym trawnikiem oraz krzewami :porzeczką,borówką i maliną.w aneksie kuchennym meble w zabudowie a w wyposażeniu: kuchenka gaz    ++-NBP-++')]
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: [('zabudow:', 'ami :porzeczką,borówką i maliną.w aneksie kuchennym meble w zabudowie a w wyposażeniu: kuchenka gazowa amica,z piekarnikiem ele    ++-NBP-++'), ('zabudow:', ' przeszklona ława.w drugim pokoju sypialni ok.15mkw:szafa w zabudowie typu komandor oraz duże łóżko i dwie szafki nocne.łazienk    ++-NBP-++')]
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_j: []
lista_k: [[], [], [], [('gospodarcze:', 'arkingowe na samochód ,rower ale również jako pomieszczenie gospodarcze z półkami. cena najmu do negocjacji,warunkiem jednak koniec    ++-NBP-++')], [], [('parking:', 'ie do garażu.przed garażem podjazd i ogólnodostępne miejsca parkingowe . w pobliżu wiele sklepów,między innymi dwa supermarkety    ++-NBP-++'), ('parking:', 'z śmieci i f. remontowy.garaż do wykorzystania jako miejsce parkingowe na samochód ,rower ale również jako pomieszczenie gospod    ++-NBP-++')], [], [('garaż:', 'nie dwupokojowe usytuowane na parterze z tarasem ,ogrodem i garażem.budynek wybudowany w 2007r. na nowym kameralnym,bezpieczn    ++-NBP-++'), ('garaż:', 'ience piec dwuobiegowy typu vaillant .z ogrodu przejście do garażu.przed garażem podjazd i ogólnodostępne miejsca parkingowe     ++-NBP-++'), ('garaż:', 'uobiegowy typu vaillant .z ogrodu przejście do garażu.przed garażem podjazd i ogólnodostępne miejsca parkingowe . w pobliżu w    ++-NBP-++'), ('garaż:', ' 220zł w nim zaliczka na wodę , wywóz śmieci i f. remontowy.garaż do wykorzystania jako miejsce parkingowe na samochód ,rower    ++-NBP-++')], [('ogród:', 'in.salon z aneksem kuchennym ok 24mkw z wyjściem na taras i ogród.taras w częsci zadaszony z kącikiem z siedziskiem oraz ozdo    ++-NBP-++'), ('ogród:', 'kiem z siedziskiem oraz ozdobną pergolą w części otwarty na ogród z zadbanym trawnikiem oraz krzewami :porzeczką,borówką i ma    ++-NBP-++')], [('ogrod:', 'ne mieszkanie dwupokojowe usytuowane na parterze z tarasem ,ogrodem i garażem.budynek wybudowany w 2007r. na nowym kameralnym    ++-NBP-++'), ('ogrod:', 'umywalką i wc. w łazience piec dwuobiegowy typu vaillant .z ogrodu przejście do garażu.przed garażem podjazd i ogólnodostępne    ++-NBP-++')], [], [], [], [], [], [], [('remon:', 'o zarządcy 220zł w nim zaliczka na wodę , wywóz śmieci i f. remontowy.garaż do wykorzystania jako miejsce parkingowe na samoc    ++-NBP-++')], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [('aneks:', 'miejskiej-szybki dojazd do centrum miasta ok.10 min.salon z aneksem kuchennym ok 24mkw z wyjściem na taras i ogród.taras w cz    ++-NBP-++'), ('aneks:', 'anym trawnikiem oraz krzewami :porzeczką,borówką i maliną.w aneksie kuchennym meble w zabudowie a w wyposażeniu: kuchenka gaz    ++-NBP-++')], [], [], [], [], [], [('zabudow:', 'ami :porzeczką,borówką i maliną.w aneksie kuchennym meble w zabudowie a w wyposażeniu: kuchenka gazowa amica,z piekarnikiem ele    ++-NBP-++'), ('zabudow:', ' przeszklona ława.w drugim pokoju sypialni ok.15mkw:szafa w zabudowie typu komandor oraz duże łóżko i dwie szafki nocne.łazienk    ++-NBP-++')], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[]
```

OUTPUT (IMG): https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5qQi.png

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really tired with this right now. I want to make one list like this ['','','',garage+garage+garage,'','','',kitchen+kitchen,'',''].

Comment: It's because you reinitialize `lista_j = []` during every iteration in the loop. Move `lista_j = []` out of the loop.

Comment: nope, returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that during every iteration over the loop, you initialize `lista_j` over and over again. You need to move it out of the loop.

Untested, but should work:

```
for p in page_soup.select('section#description'):
            p = str(p)
            p = p.lower() 

            lista_k = []  
            lista_j = []

            for j in range(len(HEADERS3)): 
                #print('j:',j)
                # find_p znajduje wszystkie słowa kluczowe z HEADERS3 w paragrafie na stronie kontraktu.
                find_p = re.findall(HEADERS3[j],p)
                # listy, które wyświetlają pozycję startową poszczególnych słów muszą zaczynać się od '-' lub 0?,
                # ponieważ, gdy dane słowo nie zostanie odnalezione to listy będą puste w pierwszej iteracji pętli
                # co w konsekewncji doprowadzi do błędu out of range
                m_start = []
                m_end = []



                for m in re.finditer(HEADERS3[j], p):
                    #print((m.start(),m.end()), m.group())
                    m_start.append(m.start())
                    m_end.append(m.end())

                #print(h)

                for k in range(len(m_start)):
                    #właściwe teraz nie wiem po co to jest..
                    try:
                        x = m_start[k]
                        y = m_end[k]
                    except IndexError:
                        x = m_start[0]
                        y = m_end[0]
                    #print('xy:',x,y)
                    #print(find_p) 
                #print(HEADERS3[j])
                    z = (HEADERS3[j]+':',p[-60+x:y+60]+'    ++-NNN-++') 
                    lista_j.append(z)
                    #print(z)
                #print ('lista_j:',lista_j)
                lista_k.append(lista_j)
            print('lista_k:',lista_k)
```

Or even outside the first `for` loop, depending on your case:

```
lista_k = []
lista_j = []
for p in page_soup.select('section#description'):
            p = str(p)
            p = p.lower() 

            for j in range(len(HEADERS3)): 
                #print('j:',j)
                # find_p znajduje wszystkie słowa kluczowe z HEADERS3 w paragrafie na stronie kontraktu.
                find_p = re.findall(HEADERS3[j],p)
                # listy, które wyświetlają pozycję startową poszczególnych słów muszą zaczynać się od '-' lub 0?,
                # ponieważ, gdy dane słowo nie zostanie odnalezione to listy będą puste w pierwszej iteracji pętli
                # co w konsekewncji doprowadzi do błędu out of range
                m_start = []
                m_end = []



                for m in re.finditer(HEADERS3[j], p):
                    #print((m.start(),m.end()), m.group())
                    m_start.append(m.start())
                    m_end.append(m.end())

                #print(h)

                for k in range(len(m_start)):
                    #właściwe teraz nie wiem po co to jest..
                    try:
                        x = m_start[k]
                        y = m_end[k]
                    except IndexError:
                        x = m_start[0]
                        y = m_end[0]
                    #print('xy:',x,y)
                    #print(find_p) 
                #print(HEADERS3[j])
                    z = (HEADERS3[j]+':',p[-60+x:y+60]+'    ++-NNN-++') 
                    lista_j.append(z)
                    #print(z)
                #print ('lista_j:',lista_j)
                lista_k.append(lista_j)
            print('lista_k:',lista_k)
```

Comment: it stil is i j loop so it makes 43 times. Also the is nested tuples in loop, how to take it out to one list?

Comment: yes much better! But now it is something like this: lista_k: [[('kuchni:', '(2018r.) na ul. kusocińskiego. pokoje częściowo umeblowane, kuchnia wyposażona w lodówkę, kuchenkę i meble. łazienka z kabiną     ++-NNN-++'), ('opłat:', 'we, fitness itp. czynsz najmu wynosi 1850 złotych dodatkowo opłaty za energię elektryczną oraz opłaty do zarządcy w wysokości    ++-NNN-++'), There are nested (tuples?) inside list. How to get rid them of?